# Autotools: top_srcdir and abs_top_srcdir are empty

Tags: autotools, autoconf, libtool

i'm currently trying to include a libtool library from another project that lies beside my current project. I can check the library in configure using

```
LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -L$top_srcdir../otherproject/libotherproject/.libs/"
AC_CHECK_LIB([otherproject],[init],[],[AC_MSG_ERROR([No otherproject libary found.])])
```

in my configure.ac. Everything is fine so far. But if i build the project using make, i get an error from libtool while it is in currentproject/sources/:

```
../libtool: line 5986: cd: ../otherproject/libotherproject/.libs/: No such file or directory
libtool: link: cannot determine absolute directory name of `../otherproject/libotherproject/.libs/'
```

Which is logical, because it should be something like `../../otherproject/libotherproject/.libs/`. I tried to debug that and found that if is use

```
AC_MSG_NOTICE([Top src dir is: $top_srcdir])
```

in configure.ac, the config script tells me

```
configure: Top src dir is:
```

only. Same behaviour for $abs_top_srcdir. $srcdir is "." always. I digged a bit in the documentation and found that $builddir should always be ".", but is also empty in my case. Is this a bug? Maybe i forgot to call a `AC_init_anything` ? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not sure if you really mean to use the `.libs` subdirectory with libtool. You should just pass `<path>/libxxx.la`. What steps are you using to generate the `configure` script(s) and `Makefile.in` templates?

Comment: im usually executing autoconf and automake to generate my files. Where should i pass the path to the .la-File?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `srcdir` as a variable to determine the path to a built object. Use `$(top_builddir)` instead.

To use Makefile variables you need to use brackets either `$()` or `${}`.

Comment: I have the same problem with `ac_srcdir`. The problem is, the Autoconf manual says to use `ac_srcdir`; see Autoconf manual, [Configuration Files | 4.6 Performing Configuration Actions](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Configuration-Actions.html). Any ideas why the manual says to use `ac_srcdir` which is empty? (`top_builddir` is also empty, but I don't see it documented in the manual).